# Why does os_log(), available on iOS 10 work on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that needs to support iOS 9.3 and above. I was trying [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) which is only available on iOS 10.0+ (specific method: [os_log](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_log)).

Here's how I used it:

```
#include <os/log.h>

os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "this is a log");
```

I expected it to crash on iOS 9.3. To my surprise, when I ran the app on iOS 9.3 simulator and then an iPhone, it ran fine. I tried cleaning and then rebuilding but it still worked.

Why would the `os_log()` still work on an iOS version it's not supposed to be on?

Comment: It could be that it wasn’t public in iOS 9, but it was still there.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Interesting. Just out of curiosity, can I get in trouble for using a private API in this case if I don't gate it?

Comment: That’s hard to tell. From what I understand, they analyze the binary to find references to private APIs, but I don’t know how they handle APIs that were private and became public.

Comment: May be documentation error. There is no availability marks that is available since 10.0

Comment: The `os` framework actually goes back to iOS 8 by the way. So who knows what was being built in before they announced it at WWDC 2016? That sort of thing happens quite often.